# Pandas: Aggregating column slices as arrays

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks as such:

```
                      Scaled
               Date 
2020-07-01 02:40:00 0.604511
2020-07-01 02:45:00 0.640577
2020-07-01 02:50:00 0.587683
2020-07-01 02:55:00 0.491515
....
```

I am trying to add a new column called `X` which is supposed to look as such, where every two previous values become an array:

```
                      Scaled   X
               Date 
2020-07-01 02:40:00 0.604511 nan
2020-07-01 02:45:00 0.640577 nan
2020-07-01 02:50:00 0.587683 [0.604511 0.640577]
2020-07-01 02:55:00 0.491515 [0.640577 0.587683]
...
```

I am trying a `for`-loop to do so, but I don't think this is the most elegant and efficient way, so any suggestion of how to do this in pandas? (but it is not going as intended)

```
window_size = 2
for i in range(window_size, df.shape[0]):
    df['X'][i] = df['Scaled'][i - window_size:window_size]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use pandas, you may use list comprehension and `concat` and `shift`

```
window_size = 2
df['X'] = (pd.concat([df.Scaled.shift(-i) for i in range(window_size)], axis=1)
             .shift(window_size).values.tolist())

Out[213]:
     Scaled                               X
0  0.604511                      [nan, nan]
1  0.640577                      [nan, nan]
2  0.587683  [0.604511, 0.6405770000000001]
3  0.491515  [0.6405770000000001, 0.587683]
```

Comment: Best solution so far!

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea with using a for loop.

First you have to initialize the new column you can use `.apply()` on your dataframe to do this.

Then you can use `.iterrows()` to iterate through the indices of the dataframe creating your desired array as you iterate through the rows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': ['2020-07-01 02:40:00', '2020-07-01 02:45:00', '2020-07-01 02:50:00', '2020-07-01 02:55:00'], 'Scaled': [0.604511, 0.640577, 0.587683, 0.491515]})

df['New_col'] = df['Scaled'].apply(lambda x : float("NAN"))

for i, val in df.iterrows():
  if i == 0 or i == 1:
    scaled_a = None
    scaled_b = None
  else:
    scaled_a = df['Scaled'][i-2]
    scaled_b = df['Scaled'][i-1]
  df['New_col'][i] = [scaled_a, scaled_b]
```

Simply assign the value of your new column to the value of the dataframe Scaled column at the previous two indices an save it in an array. Hope this helped!!

```
    Date                Scaled      New_col
0   2020-07-01 02:40:00 0.604511    [None, None]
1   2020-07-01 02:45:00 0.640577    [None, None]
2   2020-07-01 02:50:00 0.587683    [0.604511, 0.640577]
3   2020-07-01 02:55:00 0.491515    [0.640577, 0.587683]
```

The result should look something like this. ^^

Comment: Thank you, but I trust there should be a more elegant solution. Also, the window_size is a variable and this is hardcoding this value

Answer (score 0):

**updated**
Identical output.  This is a pandas implementation. Uses numpy generate list that is pandas column for df that is super efficient.

```py
d = list(pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,7,1), dt.datetime(2020,7,2), freq="15min"))
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":d, 
      "Scaled":[round(Decimal(random.uniform(0, 1)),6) for x in d]})


# generate two new arrays that are shifted version of *scaled*
a1 = np.roll(df["Scaled"],1)
a1[0:2] = None
a2 = np.roll(df["Scaled"],2)
a2[0:2] = None
# combine them into a list and put back into df
df['X'] = np.vstack((a2, a1)).T.tolist()

print(df[:10].to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
               Date    Scaled                     X
2020-07-01 00:00:00  0.396534          [None, None]
2020-07-01 00:15:00  0.890777          [None, None]
2020-07-01 00:30:00  0.241534  [0.396534, 0.890777]
2020-07-01 00:45:00  0.800615  [0.890777, 0.241534]
2020-07-01 01:00:00  0.161382  [0.241534, 0.800615]
2020-07-01 01:15:00  0.727410  [0.800615, 0.161382]
2020-07-01 01:30:00  0.146833  [0.161382, 0.727410]
2020-07-01 01:45:00  0.925441  [0.727410, 0.146833]
2020-07-01 02:00:00  0.770211  [0.146833, 0.925441]
2020-07-01 02:15:00  0.310082  [0.925441, 0.770211]
```

Comment: This is a different output than the one I presented, also, I understand that NumPy is faster and I have this fully implemented in NumPy but I want specifically do it in Pandas

Comment: @Adam I've updated - you will see it really is so marginally different.  Using `None` instead of `np.nan` and resetting first two rows in both shifted arrays before they are combined

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version without the for loop.  First, create the data frame:

```
from io import StringIO

data = '''Date  Scaled 
2020-07-01 02:40:00  0.604511
2020-07-01 02:45:00  0.640577
2020-07-01 02:50:00  0.587683
2020-07-01 02:55:00  0.491515
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s\s', engine='python')
```

Next, use `shift()` to get previous values, and the lambda function creates the 2-element list or yields a single NaN:

```
f = lambda a, b: np.nan if np.isnan(a) or np.isnan(b) else [a, b]

window_size = 2

t = (pd.concat([df['Scaled'].shift(window_size).rename('a'), 
                df['Scaled'].shift(window_size - 1).rename('b')], axis=1
          )
       .apply(lambda x: f(x['a'].round(6), x['b'].round(6)), axis=1))

print(t)

0                     NaN
1                     NaN
2    [0.604511, 0.640577]
3    [0.640577, 0.587683]
dtype: object
```

Comment: If you change the window_size to 3, this will not make the array 3 elements

Comment: I understand now, you're looking for, say [0.604, 640, 587] as one cell of the new column.  Is that right?

Comment: maybe I should have specified more. The non-working code was showing this. Yes.